# Need to filter all rows in postgres where records share a common id but any one fails to pass a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table in Postgres that looks something like this:

```
table
------
id        varchar(10)
reversed  boolean
status    varchar(3)
group_id  varchar(10)
```

The algorithm is if any single record has `reversed = true` or `status = foo`, all records with the same `group_id` should be filtered. If `group_id` is null, which is possible, I'd like to keep those records regardless of `reversed` or `status`

The closest I've gotten is with a `NOT IN` subquery:

```
select * 
from 
  table 
where 
  group_id 
not in (
select 
  group_id 
from 
  records 
where 
  reversed = true 
or 
  status = foo
)
```

but `NOT IN` also filters nulls naturally which i don't want. have also tried not exists and inner joins but haven't quite gotten the right syntax. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by adding `group_id is null` in `where` condition,

```
select * 
from table 
where group_id not in 
(
  select 
    group_id 
  from records 
  where (reversed = true or status = foo)
)
or group_id is null
```